# Draw a graph from an incidence matrix in Excel

Tags: graph-theory, math-software

I am trying to study the social network of the center where I am working. I have done a compilation of relation between personal from programed meeting, formal working team, etc. to analyze structural relevant positions. I recapitulated all these information in a matrix of incidence: a square symmetric matrix which entries are related with the time two persons stay together. This matrix is in Excel.

I am looking for free software which draws a graph from the incidence matrix via importation of Excel file.

Any help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I can't offer specific software recommendations, but know that Excel can save files as comma separated value or tab delimited (.csv or .tab) files, which are pretty much universal for data-driven software.  So, no need to limit your search only to programs that can read from excel files.

Comment: Ok. If I save data in .csv for example, are there software to make graph from incidence matrix?

Comment: Yup, looks like R will do it.  I've added an answer with links to it and the necessary package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like [R](http://www.r-project.org/) can generated the graph youre looking for via [graph.incidence](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/igraph/html/graph.incidence.html) in the igraph package, which can be found in CRAN.  To get the incidence matrix, you can just do:

```
x=read.csv("C:/yourfilenale.csv")
matrix.pickaname <- as.matrix(x)
```

Though, it seems that this solution only works if the .csv is only the data, no headers.  If you still have string values in the file, it gets imported as a data.frame.

Comment: Is this for logic matrix only?

Comment: The documentation I linked indicates it takes an incidence matrix.  This isn't exactly my area though, so I can't attest to it.  R is free though, and very effective so I'd give it a shot.